# Receive an error message when I type rake run:iphone on my Mac terminal

Tags: ios, ruby, macos, terminal, rhodes

I'm trying to build a Rhodes application for Iphones and I'm following a tutorial (http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/2.2.0/rhodes/tutorial). When I type in the command ***rake run:iphone*** in my terminal I receive an error message.

Error message:

*can not found XCode command line tools
Install XCode to default location
For XCode from 4.3 and later - you should install Command Line Tools package ! Open XCode - Preferences... - Downloads - Components - Command Line Tools*

I've installed Xcode several times and installed the command line tools so I'm not sure why I am continuing to receive this error.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try `bundle exec rake run:iphone`

Comment: I have not tried your suggestion since I'm thinking about solely using xcode to create my app. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you accepted the Xcode terms of service?
In the past that has blocked things for me. 
You can open command space, type xcode and try to run it to check.

Comment: I just uninstalled and re-installed but did not get a terms of service page. Also when I run the command 'gcc' in my terminal to check if xcode is installed it says: xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Users/Username/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist, use `xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools (or see `man xcode-select`). The xcode is in my applications folder but I dragged it over to my desktop and still receiving the same error message.